# OneNote FSSHTTP

Tags: office365, onenote, fsshttp

For one of our application that needs to get connected to Office365 and Sharepoint Online we are implementing FSSHTTP functions. This to be able to modify Word documents. The impact is that once you start supporting FSSHttp, then all the other applications do use FSSHTTP as well.

We managed to be able to read and modify word files. We now need to manage OneNote files as well.

Unfortunately the format of a OneNote file in FSSHTTP is very different from the one of Word.

Word comes into zipped XML files, while the OneNote content just comes into an array of bytes.

We have arrays like this
(length=97):02 00 00 80 0F 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 0A 00 DD 34 00 88 77 34 00 0C FE 1C 00 10 3E 1C 00 14 84 1C 00 14 7A 1D 00 14 22 1C 00 1C 5B 1E 00 1C 2C 34 00 20 13 1E 00 24 00 0C 04 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 49 2E 2B 47 0C 00 00 00 53 00 61 00 6C 00 75 00 74 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 31 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

(length=87):02 00 00 80 0F 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 0A 00 DD 34 00 88 77 34 00 0C FE 1C 00 10 3E 1C 00 14 84 1C 00 14 7A 1D 00 14 22 1C 00 1C 5B 1E 00 1C 2C 34 00 20 13 1E 00 24 00 0C 04 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 49 2E 2B 47 02 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 31 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

We understand the content is in Unicode 16. We managed to find some content, but we can't really figure out what this content is and how it is formatted.

Has anybody already used this? Do you know if the OneNote content is FSSHTTP is into XML fragment (as it is for OpenXML documents)?

We could not find any documentation explaining or describing the format.

It would be very much appreciated if somebody could share some pointers, or links.

Many thanks in advance

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd924743(v=office.12).aspx

The .one file format is documented in the link above. The OneNote REST API (or Graph API) can give you an HTML representation of OneNote content, but I don't think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your link helped to find the right documentation. Best regards. Gilles